# During a fork, Where exactly does the child's execution start?

Tags: linux, operating-system, fork

**fork** system call create the duplicate process from parent. If the child create same duplicate process from the parent's, does it start executing the same kernel code that the parent was executing? Or does it start executing in user space?

Comment: Als far als I know fork is a userspace function. So which kernel space code so you mean?

Answer (score 2):

That is going to depend upon the implementation. In theory, the child process could start either in kernel mode at the end of the fork exception handler or within the wrapper function after the exception handler returns to user mode.

That said, it is generally easier to implement fork such that the child process starts executing within the tail end of the fork exception handler (kernel mode).